# How to deal with MemoryError messages while using very large arrays in plotting a function of 3 variables?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Let's assume that F(x1, x2, x3) is a function of three independent variables x1, x2 and x3 which are given in the form of 1D arrays. I would like to plot F (utilizing contour class) for a few values of x3. Below is a snippet of my code (which I assume it is where the error arises from unless otherwise is shown) includes:

```
N = 10000
data1 = [random.uniform(-1, 1) for i in range(N)]
vx = ar(data1)
data2 = [random.uniform(-1, 1) for i in range(N)]
vy = ar(data2)
data2 = [random.uniform(-1, 1) for i in range(N)]
vz = ar(data2)

def P(vx, vy, vz):
        y1 = .... # some function of vx
        y2 = .... # some function of vy
        y3 = .... # some function of vz
        return y1 * y2 * y3

X, Y = np.meshgrid(vx, vy)
vz_vals = [-1, -0.5, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 1]
num_subplots = len(vz_vals)

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
for i,vz in enumerate(vz_vals) :
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, num_subplots, i + 1, projection='3d', axisbg='gray')
    ax.contourf(X, Y, P(X, Y, vz), cmap = cm.gnuplot)
    ax.set_title('vz = %.2f' % vz, fontsize = 30)
fig.savefig('myfigure.png', facecolor='grey', edgecolor='none')
```

When I changed the code to the following, the issue resolves but now I have problem with "memory" and I don't know how to deal with it and since I am not allowed to post a new question I am hoping someone will see the problem. Thanks for all your concerns,

```
N = 10000
vx = [random.uniform(-1, 1) for i in range(N)]
vy = [random.uniform(-1, 1) for i in range(N)]
vz = [random.uniform(-1, 1) for i in range(N)]

def P(vx, vy, vz):
        y1 = .... # some function of vx
        y2 = .... # some function of vy
        y3 = .... # some function of vz
        return y1 * y2 * y3

X, Y = np.meshgrid(vx, vy)
vz_vals = [-1, -0.5, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 1]
num_subplots = len(vz_vals)

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize = (10, 4))
for i, vz in enumerate(vz_vals):
      ax = fig.add_subplot(1, num_subplots, i+1, projection = '3d', axisbg = 'gray')
      ax.contour(X, Y, P(X, Y, vz), camp = cm.gnuplot)
      ax.set_title('vz = %.2f'% vz, fontsize = 30)
fig.savefig('myfigure.png', facecolor = 'grey', edgecolor = 'none')
```

New error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "example.py", line 11, in 
>       ax.contour(X, Y, P(X, Y, vz), camp = cm.gnuplot)   File "example.py", line 2, in P
>       gauss1 = .... MemoryError

Comment: You used `[]` rather than `()`.

Comment: Did you look at the `np.meshgrid` call the error message was pointing you to?

Comment: Actually for both [ ] and ( ) it gives error. "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable"  for [ ] and "TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array for ( ).
"

Comment: `F()` is using `y1,y2,y3` which are never changed since initialization instead of it's inputs `x1,x2,x3`, was that intentional?

Comment: The function F( ) is actually a very complicated function. So, all three y's are functions of x1,x2,x3 and I just kept them more structured buy breaking it down into pieces. So, y's are intermediate functions if you well. By x1,x2 and x3 I really mean three spatial dimensions. But it happens that my F is a complicated function of y's which themselves are functions of x's.

Comment: I listened to Tadhg McDonald-Jensen and changed [ ]  to ( ) but the error still persists.

Comment: As I took a look at /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py, I noticed that there is a line in it saying: if z.ndim != 2:
            raise TypeError("Input z must be a 2D array.") Does anyone knows if there is another module which would work just fine with this particular example?

Comment: @Ashur The question after edit looks completely different than original, If you've new question please [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question, don't edit the same question.

Comment: Thanks Tushar for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to call `np.meshgrid[x1, x2]` you need to use round brackets like `np.meshgrid(x1, x2)`,

Comment: To request clarification on a question, leave your feedback as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry dear Tadhg for not leaving a tick mark as "being solved." I should have done this long time ago. I think this was the reason I earned negative comments. And thanks TigerhawkT3 for the comment made. I think I should be more careful to follow the rules. Do you think these are the reasons my account has been blocked? Hopefully not.